# Почему периодически при генерации случайного числа ничего не выводится в консоли?

Tags: c#, генерация-случайных-данных

Решил проверить кое-что, написав в качестве примера псевдослучайную генерацию с помощью Random и в зависимости от сгенерированного числа будет выдавать ответ.
Но примерно каждый третий запуск выдаёт мне пустой терминал
В чём может быть дело?

Пример кода прилагаю

```
using System;

namespace TemperatureTester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Random Temperature = new Random();
            int temperature = Temperature.Next(20, 45);


            if (temperature <= 30)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Температура равна {temperature}, вода остыла!");

            }
            else if (temperature >= 40)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Температура равна {temperature}, риск ожогов!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а что должно вывести, если случайное число равно 35?

Comment: Очевидно, потому что при значениях от 31 до 39 ваша программа ничего и не пытается выводить

Answer (score 0):

Дело в логике конструкции `if..else`.

В данном случае вывод сообщения происходит при `temperature <= 30` и `temperature >= 40`.

При других же случаях у вас выводов нет. Для тестирования можете написать так (в конце метода Main):

```
Console.WriteLine("hello, world");
```

Данная строка будет выводиться всегда, вне зависимости от того, какое значение `temperature` в данный момент у Вас.

Comment: else  { Console.WriteLine($"Температура равна {temperature}, вода нормальная!");   }

Comment: @demonplus можно в таком случае точно так же без else, здесь суть в другом, показать продолжение выполнения потока